# Incompatibility between soul/tikz and accents package

Tags: tikz-pgf, accents, soul

The following code throws an error.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{accents}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{soul}
\def\ubar#1{\underaccent{\bar}{#1}}
\begin{document}
$\ubar{x}$
\hl{$\bar{x}$}
\hl{$\ubar{x}$}
\end{document}
```

If the line `\hl{$\bar{x}$}` is commented out, it runs fine, isolating the problem to be with the interaction between the `\hl` command and the `\ubar` command.    Is there an easy workaround for this?

Comment: Sorry, what does `tikz` do with that? It does not run through regardless of whether or not one loads `tikz`.

Comment: If you add tikz to marijn's MWE, you'll see that the `ubar{x}` command is highlighted instead of being underlined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a variant of §22 of the `soul` [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/soul/soul.pdf), you can put the content in a savebox before highlighting/underlining it. This means that linebreaks will not work but otherwise it works fine.

MWE, showing a manual savebox and a new command `\hlu` that performs the box operations:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{accents}
\usepackage{soul}
\newsavebox{\ubarbox}

\def\ubar#1{\underaccent{\bar}{#1}}
\def\hlu#1{\savebox{\ubarbox}{#1}\hl{{\usebox\ubarbox}}}

\begin{document}
\savebox{\ubarbox}{$\ubar{x}$}
\noindent ubar: $\ubar{x}$\\
hl bar: \hl{$\bar{x}$}\\
hl usebox: \hl{abc {\usebox\ubarbox}}\\
hlu: \hlu{$\ubar{x}$}\\
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: This is great, thank you.     I would ideally like to define `\ubar` in advance so that I can use the macro `ubar` both with and without the `hl` command.       I tried this: `\def\ubar#1{\savebox{\ubarbox}{$\underaccent{\bar}{#1}$}}` but it doesn't work, i.e., both `\ubar{x}` and `\hl{\ubar{x}}`   return blanks.    Could you suggest how to do this. please?    Thanks for all your help

Comment: @LeoSimon the problem is that both `\underaccent` and `\hl` do all kinds of redefinitions and substitutions when executing the command. This causes some interference which leads to the error that you encountered. A solution is to 'shield' the commands from eachother by using the `savebox`. This works by keeping the `\underaccent` command _outside_ of the argument of the `\hl`, in my definition of `\hlu` the accent is in `#1` and processing that is finished and stored in the box before `\hl` starts. With `\hl{\ubar{x}}` as you suggest the accent is back in the argument of `\hl` [...]

Comment: [...] so the original problem returns, i.e., that is not possible (or at least I did not find a way to do that so far). The `\hlu` command however works the same as `\hl` (only without line breaking), so whenever you want to highlight something that contains an underbar somewhere you can use `\hlu` and in other cases you can use `\hl`. Or if you do want line breaking for a line that contains an underbar you can put the underbar part in a savebox and use `\hl` as normal, as shown in my 'hl usebox' example.

Comment: Thanks so much for the response, I appreciate the time you spent!